# How to fix "Invalid module name in augmentation" error?

Tags: typescript

I create a fake `foo-lib` in TypeScript website using `declare module` and the code provided throws an error:

> Error: Invalid module name in augmentation. The module 'foo-lib' cannot be found. (Error code: 2664)

Here's the corresponding code snippet:

```
declare module 'foo-lib' {
  export namespace FooLib {
    interface Foo {
      prop: boolean;
    }
  }
}

import { Foo } from './foo-lib';

const a = {} as Foo;
```

Why does this error occur, and how can it be fixed?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBByAZs5AtBAJYBGW8A3gFDzwgAeADsjAC7wB2UiIAzkyhgEAMXwAZMlVp14xTmxAwcQ0fmmzZTGMiYAueKXyYonANwy6AXxk2b1Yohbsq8McnhX4OHYnhYAOgB6PEIScgtqMGROPg4oeABeKi8oPjd8CyA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module should either be resolveable

```
declare module 'vue' {
  export const x: 1
}
import { x } from 'vue';
let a = x
//  ^?
// let a: 1
```

or the file should not be a module itself

```
declare module 'foo-lib' {
  export const x: 1
}
// import { x } from 'foo-lib'; // will make the file a module and break
let a = import('foo-lib').then(m => m.x)
//  ^?
// let a: Promise<1>
```